# Internet Explorer and Edge don't show colors of a video correctly

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video, microsoft-edge

I have a video that only a small part of it changes. So I cropped the video to that part and loaded everything else as a picture to reduce size and placed the video on top of the picture. Chrome and Firefox work fine but IE and Edge change the color of the video!

[image]

Right: picture part
Left: video part

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841378/website-should-have-same-background-color-as-video). It's similar to your problem but easier because it relates only to a single color.

But you want to achieve a complete match between the full color spectrum of a picture and a video. I think, this is very hard borderline impossible due to the different compression algorithms and color spaces used in image and video compression. Also image/video decoding is not standardized in each and every detail. I mean decoders are not required to produce identical results. And when we get to all the hardware details related to showing anything on the screen, things get even more complicated.

I would recommend you use 4:4:4 chroma subsampling and the high h264 profile. You could also try reducing the colors in the still image. And don't forge to test on as many devices as possible.